# Python equivalent of spatstat's spatial point process functions

Tags: python, r, spatstat, pysal

Is there a free Python package (i.e. PySAL?) that implements the standard summary statistics for spatial point processes, e.g. the F, G, J, and K functions?

I'm happy to use R (i.e. spatstat) if that's the best option, but I want to try out some other things I already have implemented in python. The implementations don't have to be nearly as exhaustive as R, just looking for something to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing some research on this question.

- [`spatstats`](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pysal/pointpats/blob/master/notebooks/distance_statistics.ipynb) in PySAL looks like the best bet to me
- [`AstroPy`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/stats/ripley.html) has implemented Ripley's K
- It is also possible to run R code from Python using [`rmagic`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/rmagic.html) / [`rpy2`](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/index.html)

I will update this if I make any further progress!